# Can I hide Database connectivity details from hibernate cfg file?

Tags: database, hibernate

Just need to check, If there is the the way to hide Database connectivity details like username or password from hibernate configuration file:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
    <property name="username" value="system"></property>
    <property name="password" value="tiger"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Use a JNDI connection pool defined in your application server.

Comment: hey, that was just a dummy code just for an example. Yes! I am not using SYSTEM as a user account.

Comment: Can you please show me that with example, like how to do it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

1) Use JNDI

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DatabaseName" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

2) Use a  property placeholder

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        <!-- this example use the system parameter configlocation, add -Dconfiglocation -->
        <value>file:${configlocation}/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
</bean>
```

The password can be in the file database.properties which is only in the classpath for the running application and not visible to all.